# Too few arguments in function call

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to call the `void getInput` function in the main scope. But when I do this, it tells me:

> too few argument in function call.

How do I fix this?

The first void function prints the exercises. Then I call it in the next void function called `getInput`. After that I just want to call it in the `main()` function.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

void Exercices()
{
    double speed;
    int minutes;

    cout << "walking: ";
    cin >> speed >> minutes;
    cout << "running: ";
    cin >> speed >> minutes;
    cout << "cycling: ";
    cin >> speed >> minutes;
}

void getInput(string username)
{
    double weight, goal;
    string walking, running, cycling;

    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Welcome " << username << ", please enter your weight(kg): ";
    cin >> weight;
    cout << username << ", please enter speed(km/h) and minutes spent in a week for the activities below." << endl;
    Exercices();
    cout << username << ", please enter your weekly calorie burn goal: ";
    cin >> goal;

}
int main()
{
//string user_info;
    getInput();

    Exercices();

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `getInput` has 1 argument (`username`) but you gave 0 arguments when calling it (`getInput();`).

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You declared the function as `void getInput(string username)` (i.e. taking a `string` as an argument), but are trying to call it as `getInput();` (i.e. taking no arguments).

Comment: Please read the error message properly and try to understand it. It is a very straightforward error message you have got

Answer (score 6):

As the error suggests,

```
int main()
{
    string user_info;
    getInput(user_info);

    Exercices();

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You have to pass a `string` to the function `getInput(string username)` since the function definition says **it needs one**. I hope you will read and try to understand the error message before everything else in the future